# Geometrical interpretation of disjoint union

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can anybody make me understand the geometrical interpretation of the concept  $Disjoint$ $Union $? Mathematically it's fine but I'm unable to grasp it geometrically.

Comment: What makes you think there is one? The disjoint union is an operation on sets.

Comment: You mean disjoint union of topological spaces?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a visual representation of disjoint union, e.g. [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.slidesharecdn.com%2Fsetsvenndiagrams-140115140101-phpapp02%2F95%2Fsets-venn-diagrams-5-638.jpg%3Fcb%3D1390266351&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.slideshare.net%2Fzahoormirza194%2Fsets-venn-diagrams%2F10&docid=-PLPoqA0BkiQLM&tbnid=5h_XsywPs0-v7M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjn2NjKp9PfAhUH6LwKHfPABTEQMwg6KAMwAw..i&w=638&h=479&bih=637&biw=1362&q=%22disjoint%20union%22%20venn%20diagram&ved=0ahUKEwjn2NjKp9PfAhUH6LwKHfPABTEQMwg6KAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8)?

Comment: @Randall yes. Do u have any example?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the case of a topological space $X$ with two nonempty subspaces $A,B$ whose union is $X$. In general the topologies of $A,B$ do not determine that of $X$. However if $A \cap B$ is empty and a set $U$ is open in $X$ if and only if $U$ intersects $A,B$ in sets open in $X$, then intuitively  $X$ is "in two bits" and we write $X =A \sqcup B$, the *disjoint union* of $A,B$. This can also be usefully described by saying that the function $f: X \to \{0,1\}$ taking $A$ to $0$ and $B$ to $1$, where $\{0,1\}$  has the discrete topology, is continuous.

So we say $X$ is *connected* if any continuous function from $X$ to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ is constant.This characterisation is often quite useful.

I leave you to generalise to $n$ subsets, or any "disjoint union", and to draw examples.